# Can I somehow add an 'Accepts' header in an HTTP browser download request

Tags: javascript, http, browser, xmlhttprequest

I have a JS app which makes requests to a server which can return results in JSON or CSV depending on the `Accept` header. I'd like for the user to be able to click on a button and **download the CSV to the user's hard drive**.

Is there some way I can make a request and set the `Accept` header?

I know there are other ways I can do it (different resource, query parameters), and I don't what I'm describing is possible, but it would be nice to do it 'correctly' if I can.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have tagged this `xmlhttprequest`, you can use `setRequestHeader('header name', 'header value')`. [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#setRequestHeader()).

Comment: It was tagged `xmlhttprequest` speculatively. Will using it allow the the downloading of the resource?

Comment: @Joe — I've seen approaches using `data:` URIs that make it possible. There's no other way to make an HTTP request from a browser while specifying the accept header from JS though.

Comment: To clarify, when I say 'download' I mean 'download to hard drive' not just 'make a request'. A `data:` URI assumes I've already got the data in the browser. I didn't think it was possible to do precisely what I asked. Looks like that's correct?

Comment: @Joe — That was my understanding of what you meant when I indicated the `data:` URI solution.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The API endpoint needs to exist anyway. I'll just fake it with a query string.